# How to calculate Standard Deviation of a series of numbers in wide format from a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using `SQL Server 2014` and I have table named `t1`. Extract is given below:

```
Id   n1  n2  n3  n4  n5  n6
100  3   6   10  11  18  31
101  10  15  16  22  28  37
...
```

Expected Output:

```
Id   n1  n2  n3  n4  n5  n6   StdDev
100  3   6   10  11  18  31    10.1
101  10  15  16  22  28  37     9.9
...
```

Do I necessarily need to pivot table `t1` into a long format (and use the `STDEV()` function) to perform this operation or is there another way it can be handled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `VALUES` table value constructor and `APPLY` operator:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   Id int,
   n1 int,
   n2 int,
   n3 int,
   n4 int,
   n5 int,
   n6 int
)
INSERT INTO Data (Id, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6)
VALUES
   (100,  3,   6,   10,  11,  18,  31),
   (101,  10,  15,  16,  22,  28,  37)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT d.*, c.StDev
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT STDEV(n) AS StDev
   FROM (VALUES (n1), (n2), (n3), (n4), (n5), (n6)) v (n)
) c
```

Result:

```
Id  n1  n2  n3  n4  n5  n6  StDev
100 3   6   10  11  18  31  10.1077528000375
101 10  15  16  22  28  37  9.8725207858310
```